# Java Validation Frameworks

Tags: java, validation, frameworks

I once came across a validation framework for java, where you wrote one method that protected the integrity of the data-type and any CRUD operations on that data-type automatically called this method.

Does anyone know what this framework is? I simply want to avoid repetitive validation on every CRUD method attached to a data-type.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you mean for web platform? or for RCP?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a huge list of Java Validation Libraries / Frameworks - http://java-source.net/open-source/validation

Comment: Hi Albert T. Wong, please update your answer as the link shared is no more available.

Answer (score 7):

Apache Commons has a [validation](http://commons.apache.org/validator/) framework.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Hibernate for persistence? If you are, there is [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html).

Comment: Hibernate Validator (or Bean Validation in general) is not tied to the Hibernate persistence framework (altough they work seamlessly together).

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate Validator, per adref's answer, is an implementation of JSR-303.  Here's a helpful article to get you started if you are interested:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-and-jsr-303

Answer (score 1):

[Spring](http://www.springsource.com/download/community?project=Spring%20Framework) has a very nice validation and binding API.